# google_play_service_lib.jar is missing

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I already implement my own apps with google map v2 and it was working. after updating ADT and SDK everything is getting worse. I can't find the google_play_service_lib.jar in C:\Users\\android-sdks\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject. The funny things in Eclipse it shows me that Google Play services is installed. How can I reinstall the google play services to get the jar files? I stuck in this problem for two days :( and can't find any solution in the internet.

thanks for Help

[image]

FINALLY: I delete the google play service and reinstall it. It works again now

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal that you can not find the file google_play_services.jar because it does not exist. `google_play_services` is a library of the form of a draft that you must integrate into your application this way:

- Properties (in your project)
- Android
- Add a library project

If you cant't find your library, do this :

- Propreties (in google-play-services-lib)
- Android
- Check **`'is library'`**

And

- In the project properties -> java build path -> order and export make sure that all your jars in the libs folder are checked.
- And "Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties"
- And "Project -> Clean"

I hope I have helped you!

Comment: Yes and this is my problem. I already went throw the steps that you mention it and I can't find the library.

Comment: Ok, I have to correct my answer!

Comment: thanks for your help man but this is really strange. it still doesn't work for me. I'am thingking to delete the google play service package and reinstall it again. is it a goog idea? can I do that?

Comment: Yes, I delete the google play service and reinstall it again. IT WORKS AGAIN

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing named "google_play_services.jar" anymore. You have to include the Google Play Services project as a reference in your Android Project. You can find details [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) about how to setup your project with the new Google Play Services structure.
To summarize:

- After updating the Google Play Services from the "extras" in your SDK manager, you would find a project named "google_play_services" if you go to "/extras/google/"
- install a compatible version of Google API (see the doc for details)
- Copy the library project "/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/" to your projects directory (e.g. where you generally keep your projects)
- Open Eclipse and import that library project.
- Reference this project in your Android project.

And, you should be ready to go!

But remember: You have to use either:

- A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.2 or higher and includes Google Play Store.
- The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

- When you are importing `google_play_services` lib in your workspace, make sure you copied it as well.
- Do not forget to keep the library open... We usually have a habit of keeping the projects close.. so just an advise..